# Sound play when multiple target detected. UNITY Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Currently im doing a AR audio book which is when scan multiple image target the sound will play for each target. Im trying to do follow the tutorial given by Unity and vuforia but still no working. can u help me out.

This scene contains bird and tiger. When image bird is scan the bird sound will play also the tiger.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;


public class ImageTargetPlayAudio : MonoBehaviour,
                                            ITrackableEventHandler
{
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

    void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            // Play audio when target is found
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
        else
        {
            // Stop audio when target is lost
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

And image attached is my hierarchy.
[image]

I adding this code into each image target.

Correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Docs for `RegisterTrackableEventHandler`

> This method registers a new Tracker event handler at the Tracker.
>   These handlers are called as soon as ALL Trackables have been updated
>   in this frame.

So you use the wrong method, check the [document](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1TrackableBehaviour.html#aab858de816196417c8aa541c8eab5f82), maybe `OnTrackerUpdate` is appropriate.

Comment: Sorry im not understand. im quiet new in vuforia unity. Can u explain briefly?

Comment: ___These handlers__ are called as soon as ALL Trackables have been updated_, is this hard to understand?

Comment: `RegisterTrackableEventHandler` works for all trackables

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Vuforia you will be able to handle it easier with `GetComponent` on the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`, that script contains the `OnTrackingLost` and `OnTrackingFound` events already working.

Just add a `GetComponent` for your custom script and if not `null`, play the sound on that script.

Comment: is it just add script in DefaultTrackableEventHandler? I dont know where to add. I tried add but script is error :(

Comment: That script (`DefaultTrackableEventHandler`) is attached to every Image of Vuforia (attach a screenshot of your ImageTarget GameObject please), inside you can do something like this.

    `GetComponentInChildren<MyScrypt>().TriggerSomething();`

Do this on `OnTrackingFound` and `OnTrackingLost` events and you have your custom behaviours.